# How do I sign out when using a custom google sign in button

Tags: google-signin

I am integrating google sign in to my website and am able to do so. I followed this [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) by google, using a button with custom graphic. Now, only the sign in documentation is given for custom buttons. I'd also like to integrate sign out capabilities. Is it the same as the standard google button's sign out documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) ?

Answer (score 0):

[There is no sign-out button provided by google](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25035424/6532618)

Customize one yourself and use the sign out logic of the documentation you [stated](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#sign_out_a_user)